# Google chrome printing issue

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery plugin to print a specific div of my web page. It works fine in Firfox and IE. But unfortunately its not working on Google Chrome. Actually Google Chrome is printing Complete web page including the Banner, Menus, and buttons as well. I am unable to solve this problem.

Here is my sample code

**Java Script**

```
$(function () {
    $("input:button").click(function () {
        $("#print").printThis();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<input type="button" value="print" />
<div id="print">
this is print area, it can be everything. this is print area, it can be everything. this is print area, it can be everything. this is print area, it can be everything. this is
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would help to know which plugin you're using. Anyway in most cases it's easiest to use CSS to define printable areas unless you want to offer separate print sections in addition to printing the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "pure" jQuery to do the same:

```
    //Begin browser detection section
var isOpera = !! window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'; // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !! window.chrome && !isOpera; // Chrome 1+
var isIE = false || !! document.documentMode; // At least IE6
    //End browser detection section

    //User click on something
$('a[href="#print"]').on("click", function () {
    var data = "<div> a lot of HTML code from AJAX call or from your DIV </div>";
            CreateWindow(data);
});


function CreateWindow(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
    var myWindowContents = '<html>' +
        '<head>' +
        '<title>Results</title>' +
        '<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' +
        '</head>' +
        '<body >' + data +
        '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js type="text/javascript">' + '<' + '/script>' +
        '<script type="text/javascript">' +
        '$(document).ready(function () {' +
        '});' +
        '<' + '/script>' +
        '</body>' +
        '</html>';
    mywindow.document.write(myWindowContents);
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();
    if (!isChrome) {
        mywindow.print();
    }
}
```

You also can look at **my code here**: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/2pn4p/ 
I think it will give you an idea how to solve your issue.